# JavaScript Drag and Drop - Dragging Copies

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am attempting to create a robust drag-and-drop event scheduler. I have almost all of it complete, but am stuck on one element: how to drag a copy of an item.

You can see the current version running here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bnqeLdm1/)

What I would like to be able to happen is this:

1. When a LeadIn event is dragged from the Events column to a Screen column, the original LeadIn event should stay in the Events column.
2. When a LeadIn event is dragged from a Screen column to another Screen column, the event should be moved to the new column.
3. When a LeadIn event is dragged from a Screen column to the Events column, the event should be removed from the Screen column and not appear in the Events column.
4. There should always be only one LeadIn event in the Events column.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, here is my current code:

#### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sortable Event Scheduler</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column" id="events">
            <div class="column-header">Events</div>
            <ul class="sortable-list">
                <li class="event" data-duration="00:15:00">
                    <div class="event-title">Welcome</div>
                    <div class="event-start-time"></div>
                    <div class="event-duration">Duration: 00:15:00</div>
                    <div class="event-end-time"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="event lead-in-event leadin-event" id="leadIn" data-duration="00:01:00" data-event-type="">
                    <div class="event-title">LeadIn</div>
                    <div class="event-start-time" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <div class="event-duration" style="display: none;">Duration: 00:01:00</div>
                    <div class="event-end-time" style="display: none;"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="event" data-duration="00:05:10">
                    <div class="event-title">Film 1</div>
                    <div class="event-start-time"></div>
                    <div class="event-duration">Duration: 00:05:10</div>
                    <div class="event-end-time"></div>
                </li>
                <li class="event" data-duration="00:09:40">
                    <div class="event-title">Film 2</div>
                    <div class="event-start-time"></div>
                    <div class="event-duration">Duration: 00:09:40</div>
                    <div class="event-end-time"></div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="friday-screen-1" data-start-time="18:00:00">
            <div class="column-header">Friday - Screen 1</div>
            <ul class="sortable-list">
                <!-- Add events here -->
            </ul>
            <div class="column-total-duration"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="saturday-screen-1" data-start-time="08:30:00">
            <div class="column-header">Saturday - Screen 1</div>
            <ul class="sortable-list">
                <!-- Add events here -->
            </ul>
            <div class="column-total-duration"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="saturday-screen-2" data-start-time="08:30:00">
            <div class="column-header">Saturday - Screen 2</div>
            <ul class="sortable-list">
                <!-- Add events here -->
            </ul>
            <div class="column-total-duration"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="sunday-screen-1" data-start-time="08:30:00">
            <div class="column-header">Sunday - Screen 1</div>
            <ul class="sortable-list">
                <!-- Add events here -->
            </ul>
            <div class="column-total-duration"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" id="sunday-screen-2" data-start-time="08:30:00">
            <div class="column-header">Sunday - Screen 2</div>
            <ul class="sortable-list">
                <!-- Add events here -->
            </ul>
            <div class="column-total-duration"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui-touch-punch/0.2.3/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 20px;
}

.column {
    width: calc(16.666% - 10px); /* Equal width for 6 columns with 10px gap */
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
}

.column-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.sortable-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.event {
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.event-duration, .event-start-time, .event-end-time {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.event-placeholder {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.event-title {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.total-duration {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

#### JAVASCRIPT

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Call the sort function on page load to alphabetize the Events column
    sortEventsInEventsColumn();

    $(function() {
        $(".sortable-list").sortable({
            connectWith: ".sortable-list",
            placeholder: "event-placeholder",
            receive: function (event, ui) {
                var $targetColumn = $(this).closest(".column");

                if ($targetColumn.attr("id") !== "events") {
                    // Recalculate start and end times for the entire column
                    recalculateColumnTimes($targetColumn);

                    // Update total duration for the target column
                    updateTotalDuration($targetColumn);
                } else {
                    // Clear start and end times for the dragged event item
                    updateEventTimes(ui.item, "", "");
                }

                // Sort events in the Events column
                sortEventsInEventsColumn();
            },
            update: function (event, ui) {
                var $targetColumn = $(this).closest(".column");

                if ($targetColumn.attr("id") !== "events") {
                    // Recalculate start and end times for the entire column
                    recalculateColumnTimes($targetColumn);

                    // Update total duration for the target column
                    updateTotalDuration($targetColumn);
                } else {
                    // Clear start and end times for the moved event item
                    updateEventTimes(ui.item, "", "");
                }

                // Sort events in the Events column
                sortEventsInEventsColumn();
            },
            remove: function (event, ui) {
                var $sourceColumn = $(this).closest(".column");
                if ($sourceColumn.attr("id") !== "events") {
                    // Recalculate start and end times for the entire column
                    recalculateColumnTimes($sourceColumn);

                    // Update total duration for the source column
                    updateTotalDuration($sourceColumn);
                }

                // Sort events in the Events column
                sortEventsInEventsColumn();
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    });

    function recalculateColumnTimes($column) {
        var $events = $column.find(".event");
        var startTime = $column.data("start-time");

        $events.each(function (index) {
            var $event = $(this);
            var duration = $event.data("duration");
            var endTime = calculateEndTime(startTime, duration);

            // Update start and end times for the event
            updateEventTimes($event, "Start: " + formatTimeAMPM(startTime), "End: " + formatTimeAMPM(endTime));

            // Update startTime for the next event
            startTime = endTime;
        });
    }

    function updateEventTimes($event, startTime, endTime) {
        $event.find(".event-start-time").text(startTime);
        $event.find(".event-end-time").text(endTime);
    }

    function calculateEndTime(startTime, duration) {
        var start = moment(startTime, "HH:mm:ss");
        var dur = moment.duration(duration);
        var end = start.clone().add(dur);
        return end.format("HH:mm:ss");
    }

    function formatTimeAMPM(time) {
        return moment(time, "HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm:ss A");
    }

    function sortEventsInEventsColumn() {
        var $eventsColumn = $("#events");
        var $eventList = $eventsColumn.find(".sortable-list");
        var events = $eventList.children(".event").get();

        events.sort(function (a, b) {
            var titleA = $(a).find(".event-title").text();
            var titleB = $(b).find(".event-title").text();

            // Move the "LeadIn" event to the top of the list
            if (titleA === "LeadIn") {
                return -1; // "LeadIn" comes before other events
            } else if (titleB === "LeadIn") {
                return 1; // Other events come after "LeadIn"
            }

            // Sort other events alphabetically
            return titleA.localeCompare(titleB);
        });

        $.each(events, function (index, event) {
            $eventList.append(event);
        });
    }

    function updateTotalDuration($column) {
        var $eventList = $column.find(".sortable-list");
        var totalDuration = moment.duration();

        $eventList.find(".event").each(function () {
            var duration = moment.duration($(this).data("duration"));
            totalDuration.add(duration);
        });

        var formattedTotalDuration = formatDuration(totalDuration);
        $column.find(".column-total-duration").text("Total Duration: " + formattedTotalDuration);
    }

    function formatDuration(duration) {
        var hours = duration.hours();
        var minutes = duration.minutes();
        return hours + "h " + minutes + "m";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable (an example combining sortables and draggables): [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gasfm42v/)

```js
$(".sortable-list").sortable({
    connectWith: ".sortable-list",
    placeholder: "event-placeholder",
    items: "> :not(#leadIn)",
    receive: function (event, ui) {            
        var $targetColumn = $(this).closest(".column");

        if (ui.item.hasClass("lead-in-event")) {
            if ($targetColumn.attr("id") === "events") {
                ui.item.remove();
            }
        }
```

```js
$("#leadIn").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".column:not(#events) .sortable-list",
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css("width", $(this).width());
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.helper.css("width", "");
    }
});
```

***Notes:***

1. this implementation does not attempt to update the time bookkeeping code.
2. this implementation takes advantage of the fact that when the draggable is cloned, the id will automatically be removed from the clone.

Comment: I must have missed a notification and am now just seeing this. Thanks for responding!

It is going in the right direction, but I guess I forgot to say that there can be multiple "LeadIn" events in the Screen columns. With the suggested code, it appears there can be only one per Screen column.

Comment: Answer updated to remove logic preventing multiple Leadin events per Screen column.

Comment: OK, much closer. Thank you. However I am now seeing an issue that if there are multiple "LeadIn" events next to each other in a Screen column, I am not able to freely move the other events in-between them.

Comment: That seems to be due to the width of the LeadIn event since the text is so small. If you position your mouse to the left of the column, then it works. The width seems to be coming from an inline style added by Draggable. For the moment I've added a `stop` event option to the Draggable to work around this. This seems to be a weakness of Draggable, since all the demos seem to have a symptom of this.

Comment: I've also noticed that you sometimes need to drag items in a Sortable, it will generate the location of the placeholder based upon where your mouse is, so when dragging down for example,  if you've grabbed the event at the top, it can seem like you need to drag down an excessive amount to get the placeholder to appear below.

Comment: I've now changed it to a better behaving implementation that uses `start` as well as `stop`.

Comment: I've also discovered that dragging in a sortable can sometimes be awkward, since sometimes you can drag down so fast that you overshoot the end and the placeholder doesn't get shown, since your mouse needs to be in the column to generate the placeholder initially.